# Nav bar items not responding well in css

Tags: html, css, media, navbar

I'm creating a website for class and I have all of the pages done and now I'm writing my media queries. Everything works as expected in the media queries except the nav bar items.

This is what it originally looks like:

[image: Original Nav]

But when I start to adjust my screen size the nav bar items shrink and continue to not take up all of the nav bar like this:

[image: NewNav]

Below is my html and css code for the nav link and if anyone can help me I would be so grateful:

Html:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="members.html">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a>    </li>
    <li><a href="rushweek.html">Rush Week</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Css: Media Queries *Note: this is my nav css in the media query of @media only screen and (max-width: 64em

```
#nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
}
#nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height: 33px;
    height:33px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #ffd700;
    width:20%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 20px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border:outset;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color:#000000;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color:#000000;
}
#nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: you can't set a width on `inline` elements - try changing it to `inline-block`

Comment: Would be easier if you could share both the original CSS along with the entire media query. Looks like you could just change a single property: `#nav li{display:inline-block;}` to remedy this. Also you will want to change the width to something other than 20%, as you have more than 5 menu items.

Answer (score 4):

Use `display: inline-block;` in `#nav li`. Only block type elements can be sized like this.

**Note:** that you specified 20% as width, which in case of 6 elements would overflow. 16.6% is a 1/6th of 100%. This would still overflow, since the borders are "outside" the boxes. To handle this you should also add `box-sizing: border-box;` which displays the borders and paddings inside the width and height of the box, not outside.

Comment: Added some notes for better display.

Answer (score 2):

You have a little mistake in your code: you have 6 li-items in your list and try to give them a width of 20% each (should be 16.66% but be aware of your border!).

delete the `display:inline` and use `float:left` instead, this should give you the effect you're looking for

cheers,
Dan